# Flask-Socketio not emitting from external RQ process

Tags: python, multithreading, flask, task-queue, flask-socketio

I'm running a flask server that connects to an iOS client with Flask-Socketio. The server has to process some complicated data, and since that takes a while to solve, I do it in a background job using Redis Queue.

Communication works fine normally, but I need to emit to the client, and write to database once the job finishes, and I am trying to do that from the job function (if there is a way to let the app know when the job is finished, the app could handle all communication in one place).

To do this, I start a new instance of Socketio in the job, and connect it to the redis queue, but I think I am doing it the wrong way.

It doesn't crash, but the client are not receiving anything.

Here is my code:

***tasks.py***

```
# This is the job
def engine(path, id):
    result = process(path)
    print(result)
    socket = SocketIO(message_queue = os.environ.get('REDIS_URL'))
    socket.emit('info', result)
```

***events.py***

```
def launch_task(name, description, *args, **kwargs):
    rq_job = current_app.task_queue.enqueue('app.tasks.' + name,
                                        *args, **kwargs)
    return rq_job.get_id()

@socketio.on('File')
def got_file(file):
    print("GOT FILE")
    print(file[0])
    name = file[0] + ".csv"
    path = queue_dir + name
    data = file[1]
    csv = open(path, "w")
    csv.write(data)
    csv.close()
    print(path)
    launch_task("engine", "test", path, request.sid)
```

***__init__.py***

```
socketio = SocketIO()

def create_app(debug=False, config_class=Config):
    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.debug = debug
    app.config.from_object(config_class)

    app.redis = Redis.from_url(app.config['REDIS_URL'])
    app.task_queue = rq.Queue('alg-tasks', connection=app.redis)

    from .main import main as main_blueprint
    app.register_blueprint(main_blueprint)

    socketio.init_app(app)
    return app
```

events.py handles all communication and launches the worker.

I think my arguments are wrong when instantiating Socketio, but I don't know... there are still a lot of things I don't understand about Socketio and the background jobs.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On the app, you have to initialize your `SocketIO` object with `app` and the message queue:

```
socketio.init_app(app, message_queue=os.environ.get('REDIS_URL'))
```

On your RQ worker you are doing it right, just the message queue is used:

```
socket = SocketIO(message_queue=os.environ.get('REDIS_URL'))
```

But creating a new `SocketIO` instance each time you emit is a waste of resources, you should create a global instance that can be reused in multiple tasks handled by the worker.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! it's working perfectly now... looking back, it was a silly mistake. And yes, I created the global instance in stead! I still don't know if this is the best way to do it, but that's another problem!